# How to data merge two data frames with same variables but missing values in both data frames(?)

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

Given two data frames:

`data_1` have all the variables I need to use, but some variables have missing values`(NA)`.

```
> ID      Group                    Ne             Cars          
>  1      Control                  NA              Yes     
>  
   2      Patient                  A              NA
>
   3      Patient                  NA             No
```

`data_2` is formed by just some of the `row_names` and by some of the variables of `data_1`, but those `data_2` variables contained some of the missing values of the variables in `data_1`.

```
> ID      Ne     Cars
> 
   1       A      Yes
>
   3       B       NA
```

I need it to look like

```
>ID     Group     NE  Cars
>
1    Control       A   Yes
>
2    Patient       A   NA
> 
3    Patient       B   No
```

I have tried
`data_3 <- merge(data_1, data2, by=c("Id","Group","Ne","Cars",...), all=TRUE/and all.x=TRUE/and all.y=TRUE)`, and obviously it does not work.

How can I merge both dataframe by keeping the information of data_1 and adding the missing values of the variables (from data_2) without adding/duplicating the row_names but merging?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
    arrange(is.na(Group)) %>% fill(Group) %>% 
    arrange(is.na(Ne)) %>% fill(Ne) %>% 
    arrange(is.na(Cars)) %>% fill(Cars) %>% 
    distinct()
```

Output:

```
     ID Group   Ne    Cars 
  <int> <chr>   <chr> <chr>
1     1 Control A     Yes  
2     2 Patient A     NA   
3     3 Patient B     No
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but it does not work. It generates a dataframe as if you use all=TRUE of the merge function

Comment: @M_Anna, you're right, I've edited my post now, and it should work.

Comment: Thank @arg0naut. The code seems really nice but it does not work.  I have tried it and a warning error appears " n bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding factor and character vector, coercing into character vector"  I have checked and all the variables are character vector (?). Any ideas?. On the other hand, another possibility (but less efficient is to use merge function duplicating some columns and then use the coalesce function to combine those columns

Comment: @M_Anna this doesn't mean in itself that the code is not working - it may be just a warning that you have different types in dataframes and they were coerced to character. Could you check if there is output of the code and what it does?

Comment: I've tried with one of the variables as factors, and while it indeed throws the warning it still outputs the same table as described above. Perhaps you can copy paste what you get after applying the code?

Comment: Hi again This is what I get after applying the code. Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 3 must have names
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding factor and character vector, coercing into character vector
2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
3: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding factor and character vector, coercing into character vector

Comment: @M_Anna do you see an output in R console after applying the code above? Something else than warning? Or do you save the output in an object? If you save it in an object, can you check if it corresponds to your output?

Comment: I have checked it, and I have tried both.If I save it in an object it does not correspond to my output :S

Comment: The error is "Argument 3 must have names". Currently I don't see other option than if you provide us with a reproducible example. You can do dput(df1) and dput(df2) and copy paste the outputs in your question, then it will be easier for us to see where the problem lies.